# Make a delete button

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a digital marketplace. I'm trying to make a delete button where it will delete the product out of my admin portal. When I click the delete button it redirects me back to the product page in it says deleted but the row is still there.

```
<form action='delete.php?product_id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"' method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $loadProduct['product_id']; ?>">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-alt-danger" type="submit" name="DeleteProduct"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times text-danger"></i></button
</form>
```

Here's my delete.php code

```
<?php
  require_once('../inc/config.php');


  if(isset($_POST['DeleteProduct'])){
    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];

    $result = $db->delete('DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id = ?', array($product_id));
    if ($result) {
        header('Location: products.php?action=deleted');
    } else {
        header('Location: products.php?error=notremoved');
        }
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Are you using a framework? Database wrapper? I'm unfamiliar with `$db->delete()`.

Comment: Hey, No i'm trying use it in a html template php.

Comment: Yes but, how is `$db` defined? Also, `$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];` should probably be `$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];` and you can get rid of `?product_id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"` in your `action` attribute.

Comment: If I remove the action="" how well the submit button know where to go as i have a delete page where the delete code is hosted

Comment: @user4250240 wenn action is not set, so it redirects to the sam epage where its getting called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the querystring from the `action` attribute, but not the script name. You are using POST and have that product_id placed in the hidden `<input>`

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $loadProduct['product_id']; ?>">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-alt-danger" type="submit" name="DeleteProduct">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times text-danger"></i>
    </button
</form>
```

Then in your PHP use `$_POST['product_id']` to access that value again